# No Cuda in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: nvidia, cuda

Is there no solution for CUDA for Ubuntu 12.04? Blender uses it under windows, but Ubuntu can't handle it.

Answer (score 6):

CUDA is indeed not in the Software Center. Try downloading it from http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads.

Answer (score 3):

After struggling quite a lot with the same issue, I found out that I simply had to download Blender from blender.org, `untar` it, `launch` and voila. CUDA works without having to install anything else that the restricted nvidia driver.

Simply, do not install blender from repositories!

Comment: Thats absolutely true. CUDA Installation is NOT needed. (But in the first try I installed CUDA too - later I just did not and worked as well.) But I am wondering why Blender does not have the CUDA Support enabled by default? Why do I always have to download Blender from the webpage just to be able to enable CUDA?????

Answer (score 1):

There is a CUDA solution. Check this guide out -

http://sn0v.wordpress.com/2012/05/11/installing-cuda-on-ubuntu-12-04/